# How Hazelcast updates persistence if both MapStore and XA are used

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Folks, I've struggled to find an answer to a simple scenario that needs to be supported in my application.

Imagine my app has a Hazelcast map that persists data to MySQL database. To achieve that I would just go ahead and implement MapStore interface. Excellent, I achieved the required the durability.

However, some operations have to update HZ map and MySQL transactionally. According to the docs, MapStore doesn't support this, and I should consider XA instead. It's not a big deal or showstopper; I can rely on XA to accomplish this.

What's not clear is how HZ is going to consider that now there are both MapStore and XA "connected" to MySQL. Specifically, if I update key A in a transaction whether 1 or 2 happens:
 1. Key A be persisted twice - through MapStore interface and XA call.
 2. HZ detects that XA presents and skips the call to MapStore.

Comment: " some operations have to update HZ map and MySQL transactionally" --> can't you use [write-through map store](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.3/manual/html-single/#setting-write-through-persistence) for that requirement? Write-through operations return only when it can persist to DB and put into the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable your `MapStore` implementation manually if you use XA transactions to update your persistent store. Hazelcast doesn't have any internal mechanism to disable `MapStore` when XA transactions are used. If you don't disable it, you may end up persisting the same key twice.

Comment: Not sure that this approach suits my case. If MapStore is disabled for the time a transaction is running, then the store can miss other non-transactional updates. To prevent this, I need to stack the updates up at MapStore level and persist them once the transaction is committed. It's not ideal either because I might lose the updates if a node crashes and deal with entries versioning.

Comment: In your case, it doesn't make sense to use both MapStore and XA together. If you need some of your updates to be transactional on the persistent store, then you need to do all persistent store updates using XA. Or you can use two different maps (one with regular MapStore for non-transactional updates, one with XA for transactional updates), if it suits your use-case.